# Why http.server from http modules is labeled "not safe" in documentation?

Tags: python

If you look at  python official documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server

it says literally this:
'Warning

http.server is not recommended for production. It only implements basic security checks.'

I clearly understand http vs https and how man in the middle attacks work.
I plan to write prototype code using HTTP module, and later switch to HTTPS.

Is there anything else to consider security wise?(lets say I implement some protections, like passwords/pin codes in the http exchange between client and server and completely ignore MIM attacks, which I assume will not happen on my LAN, and if they will apply, i plan to implement https protocol to avoid it)

If yes, same problems apply to http server over https protocol wrapper?

'In my opinion' answers are welcome. I doubt I get Python language authors to answer my question here anyway.

Thanks!

I googled for answer and did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's exactly what it says: It only implements basic security checks. Does it protect against XSS? Is there any form of content security? Does it do anything against malicious requests coming in? Is there any way to have people authenticate their requests?

They are basically telling you this doesn't work out-of-the-box without doing some work on the security you need in production.

Comment: OK, for my purpose - I am not concerned with SQL injections etc. Its more of a file transfer service rather than anything. And it's 'on demand' for short time only. So its not actively listening one.